# Is this random or convenience sampling?

Tags: sampling, random-allocation

I have three randomised control trials to appraise for an assignment. Each have similar inclusion/exclusion criteria. The researcher has obtained the sample from a hospital (no mention of random assignment). Those who meet the criteria are then randomly allocated into study groups. What type of sampling is this please?

Comment: For me the title and post seem to be a bit at odds. You ask about sampling (i.e, drawing from the population) in the title and the last line  but in the post you talk about random assignment (i.e., allocation of people to groups). These two are not the same. You can have random sampling without random assignment and vice versa. So perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am new to this. Basically I have three RCT's that are comparing two different treatments. The researchers have certain inclusion/exclusion criteria. In all three RCT's the researchers have got their sample from a specific hospital. if the participants meet the criteria then they are included in the study.  The participants are then randomly allocated into groups (random assignment ha). I'm wondering what type of sample method this classified as? There is no mention of random sampling once the researchers have found the eligible participants. Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: If its only about the sampling, then for a random sample the following must hold: All units of the population (or of groups in the population) must have the same probability to be part of the sample. So, say the population is all patients with a specific disease in a hospital. Then you need a list of all those patients and draw the specified number from this list. If one patient is not ion the list, the sampling is no longer "random" (as that patient has a probability of 0 to be in the sample).

Comment: However, this is distinct from random assignment)! Indeed, frequentist concepts of statistics can be justified by randomization alone, without the need for random sampling. That's why I was asking what you're after.

Comment: Thank you! So because this is not random selection would it be classified as a convenience sample?

Comment: Depends, there are other types of sampling. If the exclusion/inclusion criteria are clear and from the set of the population meeting the conditions there is a random sample drawn, it is neither random sampling nor convenience sampling but cluster sampling or so. In general the crucial question is whether at some point the sampling units were drawn from a sampling frame with equal probability (which usually requires a sampling frame). If this is not the case, it's usually convenience sampling (but also may be something else). See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29

Comment: Perhaps it better to distinguish probability and non-probability sampling. Convenience sampling is a special case of the latter, but not all non-probability samplings are convenience samplings. If there is a probability sampling aspect, it is definitely not a convenience sampling.

Comment: There are two sample selections happening here, choosing of the hospital and choosing of the subjects inside the hospital, which one are you referring to?